# Django Import-Export import error for one-to-one field - KeyError: 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

Using:
Python 3.10.4
Django 4.06
Django-import-export 2.8.0

I am trying to import data to use as demo data into my django application. I keep getting a KeyError.

```
### models.py
class Reservation(models.Model):
    reservation = models.OneToOneField(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    delivered = models.BooleanField('Delivered',default=False)
    date_reserved = models.DateTimeField('date reserved', default=datetime.datetime.now)
    ...

### admin.py
class ReservationResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('reservation',)
        fields = (
            'reservation',
            'delivered',
            'date_reserved',
            ...
        )
class ReservationImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class: ReservationResource
@admin.register(Reservation)
class ReservationAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin, ReservationImportExport):
    fields = ["delivered","date_reserved",...]

### demo-reservations.yaml  (Note: Problem happens using different data file formats)
 - reservation: 50001
   delivered: False
   date_reserved: 7/15/2022T00:00:00+00:00
   ...
```

Here's the error (slightly obfuscated)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 661, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "c:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 353, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "c:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 340, in get_instance
import_id_fields = [
File "c:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 341, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'
```

Tried Already:

1. Removed SimpleHistoryAdmin from Admin registration
2. Put breakpoints in debugger - it is clear that it is ignoring the "import_id_fields" value. If I manually change the value to 'reservation' when it calls get_import_id_fields(self), I get further (a second issue I will ask separately - guessing stackoverflow wants 1 issue per question. someone feel free to let me know if lumping them works better.) I do see in the debugger that 'id' is the value of self._meta.import_id_fields when it gets to that call.
3. Changing the model from OneToOne to ForeignKey

Every other answer I have managed to dig up seems to say that adding that exclude id and import_id_fields should have resolved this. The only think I have **not** tried (and **really** do not want to) is changing the id/foreign key column name.

EDIT 1:
At this point, I'm almost certain this is a bug in the django-import-export package. If there is field called "id" in the model, the admin import is broken. I'm a little over my head to fully troubleshoot.
I entered a bug over on GitHub. https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1480

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347073/39296) might help you

Comment: @MatthewHegarty I followed that exact approach previously, but the problem persisted. I tried adding ‘id’ to fields under the class meta as well as the import file even though the field is not in my model (that’s the only difference from my code above). I tried that both with and without the exclude = ('id',).

Comment: It's hard to judge what is going on.  Your best bet is to use the debugger.  If `get_import_id_fields()` is not returning your declared Meta fields, then why is this.

Comment: @MatthewHegarty Thank you. After further testing, I'm confident this is a bug, and I entered a but report on GH. Linked from here in case anyone else runs into this issue and stumbles on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is found, just wanted to close the loop. I had an error in my code.

```
class ReservationImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class: ReservationResource
```

should have been:

```
class ReservationImportExport(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ReservationResource
```

That `=` instead of `:` made all the difference.