# Getting mistake while importing xlsx file into database django. Please correct my code. I cant deal with it. PLEASE

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-import-export

```
Line number: 1 - 'id'
1, 28799772, 306509594, "GOLDEN NILE AAA" MChJ, 1726294, Toshkent shahri, 
Chilonzor tumani, X.TURSUNQULOV KOʻCHASI, 38-UY, 974079981, makhmudjon.khakimjonov@mail.ru, 47190

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AbdulAziz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 708, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Users\AbdulAziz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 378, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Users\AbdulAziz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 365, in get_instance
import_id_fields = [
File "C:\Users\AbdulAziz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 366, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'
```

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    okpo = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    inn = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=False,default='Tashkilot Nomi')
    soato = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True,default='Tashkilot Adresi')
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True,default='Tashkilot Street')
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, null=True,default='+998')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=25,default='tashkilot@email.com')
    oked = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
```

views.py

```
def import_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_employee = request.FILES['myfile']
        data_import = dataset.load(new_employee.read())
        result = CompanyResources.import_data(dataset,dry_run=True)
        if not result.has_errors():
            CompanyResources.import_data(dataset,dry_run=False)        
    return render(request, 'home.html',{})
```

admin.py

```
class CompanyResources(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        models = Company
        fields = [field.name for field in Company._meta.fields if field.name != 'id']
        exclude = ['id',]
        import_id_fields = ['id',]

class CompanyAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CompanyResources
    list_display = [field.name for field in Company._meta.fields]
    
admin.site.register(Company,CompanyAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not declaring the field in your import which uniquely identifies the row.  The issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69347073/39296).

To fix, find the field in your import which uniquely identifies the row.  Add the name of this column to the model declaration.

```py
class CompanyResources(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        models = Company
        import_id_fields = ['<your field name here',]
```

If you don't have a single field which uniquely identifies the row, can you use a combination of fields?  If so, declare those fields in the list.

If you do not have fields which uniquely identify the row, import-export will not be able to function correctly.  Please see the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for more information.